# SQL Query that counts grouped by results not working as intended

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to get a table that counts the correct answers from a game.

For example I want this

```
| G.Name | E.Action 
| game 1 | correctAnswer 
| game 1 | correctAnswer 
| game 2 | correctAnswer 
| game 3 | correctAnswer 
| game 3 | correctAnswer
```

to become this

```
| G.Name | Count(*) 
| game 1 | 2 
| game 2 | 1 
| game 3 | 2
```

the problem is that im getting this instead:

```
| G.Name | Count(*)
| game 1 | 5 
| game 2 | 5 
| game 3 | 5
```

where 5 is the sum of 2+1+2

This is my query

```
  SELECT G.Name, Count(*)
    FROM enduser EU
         INNER JOIN prescription P 
                    ON EU.UserRefID = P.EndUserRefID
         INNER JOIN prescriptiongame PG 
                    ON PG.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID
         INNER JOIN games G 
                    ON G.GameID = PG.GameRefID
         INNER JOIN session S 
                    ON S.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID
         INNER JOIN entries E 
                    ON E.SessionGameRefID = S.Session
   WHERE P.EndUserRefID = 889
         AND E.Action =  'correctAnswer'
GROUP BY G.Name
ORDER BY G.Name
```

How can I solve this issue, when I googled people are using the same method but they get good results

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet money that one of your joins is inflating the result.  Strip your query down to just the critical tables: `prescription`, `session`, and `entries`.  Do you still get excessive results?  If not, try adding joins back in, one at a time, until you get over-counting.

Answer (score 0):

Your joins are somehow multiplying the number of rows.  This happens when you join tables along different dimensions that are not related to each other.   This is a common problem, but I don't understand your data structure so the following is a best-guess.

Your example can be fixed by using `count(distinct)` on something.  So try this:

```
SELECT G.Name, Count(distinct SessionGameRefID)
```

Should there be a relationship between `session` and `game`?

I wonder if this simplification of your query would fix the problem (it removes the first two tables):

```
  SELECT G.Name, Count(*)
    FROM prescriptiongame PG 
         INNER JOIN games G 
                    ON G.GameID = PG.GameRefID
         INNER JOIN session S 
                    ON S.PrescriptionRefID = PG.PrescriptionRefID
         INNER JOIN entries E 
                    ON E.SessionGameRefID = S.Session
   WHERE PG.EndUserRefID = 889
         AND E.Action =  'correctAnswer'
  GROUP BY G.Name
  ORDER BY G.Name;
```

Comment: I understood my problem, that didn't helped much. But I think i can solve this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

supposing all the joins are needed try this query:

```
  SELECT G.Name, Count(G.Name)
    FROM enduser EU
         INNER JOIN prescription P 
                    ON EU.UserRefID = P.EndUserRefID
         INNER JOIN prescriptiongame PG 
                    ON PG.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID
         INNER JOIN games G 
                    ON G.GameID = PG.GameRefID
         INNER JOIN session S 
                    ON S.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID
         INNER JOIN entries E 
                    ON E.SessionGameRefID = S.Session
   WHERE P.EndUserRefID = 889
         AND E.Action =  'correctAnswer'
GROUP BY G.Name
ORDER BY G.Name
```

Comment: I got the same results as my query unfortunatly

Comment: I solved my problem, I had a wrong connection in Session, it was with GameID and not prescriptionID. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select G.Name , count(*) from enduser EU, prescription P,prescriptiongame PG ,
games G ,session S ,entries E  where P.EndUserRefID = 889 and E.action='correctAnswer' and (EU.UserRefID = P.EndUserRefID) and (PG.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID) and (G.GameID = PG.GameRefID) and (S.PrescriptionRefID = P.PrescriptionID) and (E.SessionGameRefID = S.Session)
GROUP BY G.Name
ORDER BY G.Name
```